# Welcome to Ask Patents' newest moderator

Tags: discussion, moderation

We'd like to welcome the newest moderator to Ask Patents:

[image: George White]

He'll be joining [Eric S](https://patents.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank him for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with him as he learns the ropes!

Comment: I'm happy to help

Comment: Glad to have you moderating. I'm going to be traveling some over the next two months so it is quite timely.

Comment: Why was there no election?